# ffmpeg using php exec on korean filename exit code 1

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I can't convert a video file. Example:

```
exec(ffmpeg -i 01.시대조감.wmv 0001.mp4 -hide_banner, $output, $exit_code);
```

Just returns exit code -1

Answer (score 0):

maybe ffmpeg is not in PHP's PATH variable?

`exec ("which ffmpeg",$output,$ret); var_dump($output,$ret);` to verify, in which case, execute the absolute path to ffmpeg, eg `exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i 01.시대조감.wmv 0001.mp4 -hide_banner", $output, $exit_code);`

or maybe your korean filename has some characters with special meaning for your shell, and needs to be escaped? in which case, escapeshellarg(),

```
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ".escapeshellarg("01.시대조감.wmv")." 0001.mp4 -hide_banner", $output, $exit_code);
var_dump($output,$exit_code);`
```

Comment: did not work.. however I was able to find a way.. Ill just post my answer

Comment: @dev21 I used something like this.. exec('for i in 01.시대조감.wmv; do ' . $ffmpeg_dir .'/./ffmpeg -y -i $i ../target_folder/0001.mp4 -hide_banner; done', $output, $exit_code);  the for loop looks like it doesnt make sense but it worked. I was not able to find another solution other than this.

Comment: @dev21 btw just posted a new alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574430/1067003

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is old, but for anyone looking here's an alternative way to do it, completely avoiding the issue of "properly escaping unicode characters for your shell" or the issue of "my shell doesn't support unicode characters", by making php open the file and pipe the file contents to ffmpeg.

```
<?php
$filename="01.시대조감.wmv";
$fp=fopen($filename,"rb");
if(!$fp){
    throw new \RuntimeException("failed to open \"{$filename}\"!");
}
$ffmpeg=popen("ffmpeg -i - 0001.mp4 -hide_banner", "wb");
if(!$ffmpeg){
    throw new \RuntimeException("failed to start ffmpeg!");
}
stream_copy_to_stream($fp,$ffmpeg);
fclose($fp);
pclose($ffmpeg);
```